# How to use the if-else statements in batch programming?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch code. I want to accept a character from user and if true a set of statements should be executed else another set of statements.

i tried to do this :

```
set /p aj=

if %aj%==y
    ( 
       set of commands...
    )
else (
     another set of commands...
    )
```

But I am unable to get the perfect output am supposed to get. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code script is very long I find using `goto` easier. Try something like this:

```
set /p "aj=: "
if /i "%aj%"=="y" goto :yes

:no
REM another set of commands...
goto :post

:yes 
REM set of commands...
goto :post

:post
REM Code after if-statement
```

That way you know you don't need to `enabledlayedexpansion` and you can have very long pieces of code with little worry about formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt window, enter `if /?` or `help if`, hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and read output help.

```
set /p "aj=Continue (y/n)? "
if /i "%aj%"=="y" ( 
    rem set of commands...
) else (
    rem another set of commands...
)
```

`(` must be on same line as `if` command. `) else (` must be also on one line.

Comment: ty i tired as you suggested but it doesnt work still.
'code'
set /p "aj=Continue (y/n)? "

if /i "aj" == "y" (file1.bat) else (file2.bat)

Comment: You have tried EXACTLY what I posted copied into a text file stored as ASCII/ANSI/OEM file? That is not possible as this little code definitely works. Perhaps you saved the file as Unicode file with or without BOM (byte order mark) instead of an ASCII file. Or you added extra code which does not work.